# Variadic template expansion works differently for class and function

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

Why would the following code fail to compile for the template functions, but works fine for the template class?

```
#include <functional>

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

template<typename Ret, typename ...Args>
struct Binder
{
    static void bind1(Ret(&f)(Args...)){}
    static void bind2(std::function<Ret(Args...)> f) {}
};


template<typename Ret, typename ...Args>
static void bind1(Ret(&f)(Args...))
{
}

template<typename Ret, typename ...Args>
static void bind2(std::function<Ret(Args...)> f)
{
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Binder<int,int,int>::bind1(add);    // OK
    Binder<int,int,int>::bind2(add);    // OK
    bind1<int,int,int>(add);            // OK
    bind1(add);                         // OK
    bind2<int,int,int>(add);            // Oooh no, error. But why?
    bind2(add);                         // Oooh no, error. But why?

    return 0;
}
```

The bind1 version: `static void bind1(Ret(&f)(Args...)){}` works in both cases. The bind2 version: `static void bind2(std::function<Ret(Args...)> f) {}` only works when it is a template class member. Why would the call to bind2 version fail to compile, when the function is not a class member?

```
vartemplate.cpp:22:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
vartemplate.cpp:33:14: note:   mismatched types ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>’ and ‘int (*)(int, int)’
```

Comment: Search for the error messages online. Also, make sure that you include the error messages in your question, so the next person doing research on the issue can find them. Also, remove the "c++" from the title, that's what the tags are for. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Implicit conversion (from function to `std::function`) won't be considered in template argument deduction.